# Render optimization when frames are almost the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, optimization

Is there any way to boost rendering animation, where lots of chunks are not being changed? E.g. a sprite moving on a static background.The cycles renders some chunks over 100 times and they are every time exactly the same, can it be 'compressed'?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39732/blender-animation-layering

Comment: Maybe if nothing else works this can help, it's a commercial addon but not too expensive one https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/animated-render-border/. I am not at all affiliated with the addon or the store.